# Make only part of child elements overflow:visible

Tags: html, css

I need to have overflow-x: scroll like on first part of my [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM7nw.png), and overflow visible to div bigger than its parent like on part 2 of my [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM7nw.png).

So my problem is when I add overflow:visible to parent div, all overflows inside it are visible. I want to make overflow:visible, but keep overflow-x:scroll on parent div. Is it even possible?

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        <button onclick="action(this)" class="triggerBtn">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        <button onclick="action(this)" class="triggerBtn">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        <button onclick="action(this)" class="triggerBtn">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        <button onclick="action(this)" class="triggerBtn">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="child">
        <button onclick="action(this)" class="triggerBtn">Click</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin:auto;
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.child {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    /* transform: translateX(50%); */
    background-color: #bada55;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 200;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    text-align: center;
}

div.child.active {
    width: 400px;
    left: -50%;
    background-color: #111
}
```

Bunch of JS:

```
window.action = function(el) {
  var parent = el.parentNode;
  if(parent.classList.contains('active')) {
    parent.classList.remove("active");
  } else {
    parent.className += " active";
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, can you make a working example. Meaning providing what you got so far with html/css.

Comment: Give us some code you've already tried. We're happy to help you get to a solution but you need to do some work too.

Comment: Sure. I've created fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xMddf/2/

Comment: It is not possible to let only certain elements overflow outside of a scrolling ancestor element.

Comment: Updated fiddle - now this code works EXACTLY as mine http://jsfiddle.net/xMddf/1862/

Answer (score -1):

a quick fix is to use `!important` on your child selectors, like so:

```
.parent {
  overflow: visible;
}

.child {
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

`!important` simply tells the system to use the style instead of inheriting the parent's styling. You can also use the immediate child selector `>`.

Comment: This isn't *really* a fix, just a hack essentially. Sorry @reiallenramos. Also the child CSS selector is `>`.

Comment: @TomOakley yeah I'm pretty bugged my answer as well. I guess we just have to wait for the OP to post some code so we can devise real solutions.

Comment: @reiallenramos can u create fiddle with your solution?